# VB 2010 Express: for next error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

So I've just started learning VB and I guess I've misunderstood the tutorial I've been following because I just can't figure what I'm doing wrong here. Maybe I'm over thinking it?

The problem lies with the following line as, "IndexOutOfRangeException"

```
If aryTextLine(i) = "True" Then
```

Thanks in advance, for your help.

```
Public Function FindTabPos(ByVal low As Integer, ByVal high As Integer)
    If opCounter >= 3 Then

        Dim TextLine As String

        Dim TrueCount As Integer
        TrueCount = 0

        TextLine = ""
        Dim aryTextLine() As String
        If System.IO.File.Exists(configLoc) = True Then

            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(configLoc)
            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1

                TextLine = TextLine & objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine

            Loop

            aryTextLine = TextLine.Split(",")

            For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextLine)
                MsgBox(aryTextLine(i))
            Next i

            For i = low To high
                If aryTextLine(i) = "True" Then
                    TrueCount = TrueCount + 1
                End If
            Next i
        End If
        Return TrueCount
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Edit: I found my problem. The file that it was reading was a list. Due my misunderstanding  of how "TextLine = TextLine & objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine" was working I was trying to .Split() by a comma, rather than a new line. The following, from another question on this site, fixed it.

```
aryTextLine = TextLine.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: What are the values of low and high? How many items have aryTextLine?

Comment: For i = low To high I dont know VB very well, but shouldnt it be For i = low to high - 1?

Comment: There are 48 in aryTextLine. The values I'm currently using are 0 or 1 for low, and between 2 and 7 for high.